# Mechanism of dimedone preparation

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

From [the Wikipedia article on dimedone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimedone),

> Dimedone is prepared from mesityl oxide and diethyl malonate.

I can't really figure out the mechanism for the reaction. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Diethyl malonate is a very good nucleophile and mesityl oxide is a good Michael acceptor - does this give you a start?

Comment: Good question. Don't understand why they closed it.

Comment: @Abcd because it clearly meets the criteria for "homework question."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to start in basic conditions. Dimethyl malonate is a good nucleophile on account of the two ester groups on either side of the central carbon atom. It has a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of 12.9, which is extremely acidic for a $\ce{C-H}$ bond. The first step is a Michael addition.

[image: step 1]

The resultant enolate will equilibrate, enabling it to form a much more stable 6 membered ring. We then have a Claisen condensation.

[image: step 2]

[image: step 3]

Lastly, decarboxylation will yield dimedone.

[image]

Comment: As I was writing out the mechanism, I had essentially the same steps. However, in your second step (equilibration of the enolates), the malonate is so acidic, I wasn't sure if the enolate you have on the right would ever really be able to form. However, assuming some excess base, it would probably happen eventually, and that attack to make the six-membered ring would be fast after deprotonation, so you wouldn't need it to happen much. Okay, I feel better about it now.

Comment: The Wikipedia page said diethyl malonate, instead of dimethyl malonate (the one you've used). I'm sure there's no huge difference and the product is still obtained - but which path do you think gives better yield and why?

Comment: Methanol is more acidic than ethanol making methoxide a better leaving group in a polar solvent, so probably dimethyl malonate, but I’m sure the difference is marginal.